# Setting "allure-results" directory to current working directory

Tags: c#, nunit, specflow, allure

I am having some trouble changing the location in which my allure results are saved.

I have created an allureConfig.json file with the following

```
"allure": {
"title": "Test Results",
"directory": "allure-results",
 }
```

I have also configured the current working directory as the tests are executed with Nunit

```
    [Before]
    public void Init()
    {
        var dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(GetType().Assembly.Location) ?? throw new InvalidOperationException();

        Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(dir);
    }
```

However, the allure-results folder still remains to be created in %temp% rather than the working out folder.

If I hard code the address in the JSON file then this works, this obviously is not a permanent solution.

I am unable to find a clean usable working solution to this issue.

Any help is extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Environment.CurrentDirectory works for me.

```
    [BeforeTestRun]
    public static void BeforeTestRun()
    {
        //Set default working directory for NUnit to store allure results
        Environment.CurrentDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
    }
```

Comment: This does not work for me, the folder is still being created in the default temp directory

Comment: I have found if you run the tests via a command line using nunit3-console.exe then the above works and the test results are found in the relevant directory. But when running through the test explorer in visual studio this seems to be overwritten or ignored.

Comment: You probably are missing the Nuget package 'NUnit 3 Test Adapter' https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NUnitDevelopers.NUnit3TestAdapter#overview which allows for running NUnit tests through visual studio. Otherwise you use MSTest.

Comment: I have installed this adapter, but the folder is still being created in the incorrect location. I can see the adapter is being used from the test output.

NUnit Adapter 3.13.0.0: Test execution started